# Typesafe config secure rendeing

Tags: configuration, typesafe, typesafe-stack

I have the following code

```
log(config.render())
```

However if I have passwords in the config then they'll appear in log. Is there **easy** way to eliminate this? I am looking for something like that

```
log(config.map { if ("password" in it.key.toLowerCase()) "***" else it.value }
    .render())
```

Answer (score 0):

For now the only clear solution is to do like this

```
val contentHiddenValue = ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef("***", "Content hidden")
log.info(config.root()
        .withoutKey("security")
        .withValue("security", contentHiddenValue)
        .render())
```

The obvious disadvantage is that it hides only exact config subtree